# lstinputlisting not recognizing comment character

Tags: listings, color, input

I have some code which I like to incorporate in to my latex document. I have set up the aesthetic so the code is easy to read as follows

```
\lstdefinestyle{numbers}{numbers = left, 
    stepnumber =1, 
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbersep =5pt}
\lstdefinestyle{common}{tabsize =2, 
    showspaces =false,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    breakatwhitespace=false,  
    breaklines=true}
\lstdefinestyle{moreR}{backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    showtabs=false,
    frame=false,  
    rulecolor=\color{black}, 
    captionpos=b, 
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{green!60!black}, 
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)}, 
    morekeywords={*,...} }

\lstdefinestyle{MyRstyle}{language =R,
    basicstyle =\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
    style = numbers, 
    style = moreR, 
    style = common}
```

If I have to below code. The first comment is correctly colored but not the second.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=MyRstyle]
 ## comment 1
Larsen <- read.delim("~/Projects/Mircoarray expressed/Larson/Discovery_GPL15931/Full/Larsen.txt")
PAM50 <- read.table("~/Projects/Mircoarray expressed/Larson/Discovery_GPL15931/PAM50.txt", quote="\"", comment.char="")

## comment2
names=NULL
for (i in 1:183){
  x<-paste(colnames(Larsen)[i], PAM50$V4[i], sep = "_")
  names <- c(names, x)
}

colnames(Larsen) <-names
\end{lstlisting}
```

The same problem occurs with the lstinputlisting function

```
\lstinputlisting[style=MyRstyle]{code.R}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the standard syntax: try `\lstinputlisting[style=MyRstyle]{code.R}` and see if that fixes it. When I put your code into a minimal document and used `\lstinputlisting`, it correctly colored the comments green. But when I tried your syntax without a corresponding `\end` call, I got a syntax error!

Comment: You are correct, I had posted the wrong syntax. I have been using `\lstinputlisting`. Coloring issue persists with the correct syntax.

Comment: I have worked out the issue is to do with the code I am trying to comment. I've updated question to reflect the new problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the comments weren't being correctly called was to do with my second line of code.

```
PAM50 <- read.table("~/Projects/Mircoarray expressed/Larson/Discovery_GPL15931/PAM50.txt", quote="\"", comment.char="")
```

Where the `quote = "\""` is the issue. It appears (although not sure) that the lstlisting is calling everything a string after this point (untested theory). If I simply close the `\"` with single quotes the code works in R still and the commenting issue is resolved. (i.e. `quote = '\"'`)